# How to get all items in a list that have the same class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

How would I get all the items with the class "ingredient" and use it to create a new Ingredient? I'm using Nokogiri to grab the class. I'm doing it like this but can only create one ingredient/get the first item in the list:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://damndelicious.net/2017/01/16/turkey-and-spinach-veggie-lasagna/"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))


ingredients = Ingredient.create do |ingredient|
  ingredient.name = doc.at_css(".ingredient").text
end
```

This is an example of the list I am trying to get items from:

```
<li class="ingredient">1 tablespoon olive oil</li>
<li class="ingredient">2 cloves garlic, minced</li>
<li class="ingredient">1 onion, diced</li>
<li class="ingredient">2 zucchinis, diced</li>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `.at_css` method returns the only first match.

To get all elements that match a selector use [`.css`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri%2FXML%2FSearchable%3Acss)

```
ingredients = doc.css(".ingredient").map do |node|
  Ingredient.create!(name: node.text)
end
```